# About dropdown list

Tags: list, hover, dropdown, border

```css
ul.menu {
 background-color: #2980b9;
 display: flex;
 padding: 10px;
}

ul.menu >li {
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 10px;
 border: 1px solid aliceblue;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
}
#dropdown-1 >ul{
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 height: 30px;
 transition: .250ms  all;
}
#dropdown-1:hover >ul {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 height: 60px;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
 <header>
  <ul class="menu">
   <li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li id="dropdown-1">
    <a href="#">Branchs</a>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#">branch 1</a>
     </li>
     <li id="dropdown-2">
      <a href="#">branch 2</a>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#">sss</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">sss</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">sss</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">branch 3</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </header>
```

i have question guys. i have 1 list and 3 list item. One of these list is dropdown list and it has got 3 dropdown items. when i hover to dropdown list button, dropdown items visible but my normal list's border much longer before the hover. so i want to know how can i make my list border fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to the css file:

```
ul.menu {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
   }
   
   ul.menu >li {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
   }
   #dropdown-1 >ul{
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    transition: .250ms  all;
   }
   #dropdown-1:hover >ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
   }
```

I have changed the position of dropdown-2 to absolute and added z-index set to 1 and I have set the display of dropdown-2 to none(display: none;), and when mouse hovers over it the display property changes to block. In this way the second dropdown gets shown as a pop up without making any changes in the main menu.